# Obtener checkbox seleccionado y agruparlo por nombre

Tags: javascript, formularios, checkbox

Tengo un formulario con varios checkbox cada uno tiene su propio valor y pertenece a un grupo por el nombre.

Grupos:

- Marca
- Procesador
- RAM

```js
function evitaSubmit_filtroMarca(e) {
  console.log('Capturamos el submit');
  e.preventDefault();

  var formulario = document.getElementById('formulario');
  var checkBoxes = formulario.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');

  recorreCheckBox(checkBoxes);

  return false;
}

function recorreCheckBox(checkBoxes) {
  let result = [];
  var nombre;
  let resultados = new Object();
        
  checkBoxes.forEach(item => {
    console.log(item.name)
    nombre = item.name;
    if (item.checked) {
      result.push(item.value);
    }
  })
  resultados.nombre = result;
  console.log(resultados)
  return result;
   }
```

```html
<form id="formulario" onsubmit="return evitaSubmit_filtroMarca(event);">
    <div class="input-list p-0">
        <div class="form-check p-0">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="HP" id="marca_1" name="marca">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="marca_1">HP</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="Lenovo" id="marca_2" name="marca">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="marca_2">Lenovo</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="Intel Core i3" id="procesador_1" name="procesador">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="procesador_1">Intel Core i3</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="Intel Core i5" id="procesador_2" name="procesador">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="procesador_2">Intel Core i5</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="8 GB" id="ram_1" name="ram">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="ram_1">8 GB</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 text-center">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="btn_filtrar">Filtrar</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Como puedo obtener los checkboxes seleccionados y agruparlos en un objeto por su nombre

```
{
  "marca": [
    "Lenovo",
    "HP"
  ],
  "procesador": [
    "Intel Core i3",
    "Intel Core i5"
  ]
```

}

Cualquier ayuda o referencia sirve, estuve buscando referencias sobre este punto y no encontré alguna

Posteriormente debo recorrer el objeto por su nombre para realizar otras funciones

Comment: Hay varias formas de hacerlo, podrías agruparlos en la plantilla `html`, o usar un atributo `data-*`, etc. ¿Qué has intentado?

Comment: Recorro los checkboxes seleccionados y los agrego a un array. Lo que falta es agruparlo por nombre y añadirlo a un objeto con su mismo nombre

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usa un `FormData` para extraer los datos del formulario, y luego los agrupas con un simple ciclo `for`. Te adjunto un ejemplo:

```js
var formulario = document.getElementById('formulario');

function evitaSubmit_filtroMarca(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var formData = new FormData(formulario);
  
  var result = {};
  for(var pair of formData.entries()) {
   if(result.hasOwnProperty(pair[0]))
     result[pair[0]].push(pair[1])
   else
     result[pair[0]] = [pair[1]]     
  }
  console.log(result);
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form id="formulario" onsubmit="return evitaSubmit_filtroMarca(event);">
    <div class="input-list p-0">
        <div class="form-check p-0">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="HP" id="marca_1" name="marca">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="marca_1">HP</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="Lenovo" id="marca_2" name="marca">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="marca_2">Lenovo</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="Intel Core i3" id="procesador_1" name="procesador">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="procesador_1">Intel Core i3</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="Intel Core i5" id="procesador_2" name="procesador">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="procesador_2">Intel Core i5</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="8 GB" id="ram_1" name="ram">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="ram_1">8 GB</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 text-center">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="btn_filtrar">Filtrar</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

---

Otra posible solución, como sugiere @Marcos es usar `keys()` y `getAll()`:

```js
var formulario = document.getElementById('formulario');

function evitaSubmit_filtroMarca(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var formData = new FormData(formulario);
  
  var result = {};
  for(var key of formData.keys()) {
    result[key] = formData.getAll(key)
  }
  console.log(result);
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form id="formulario" onsubmit="return evitaSubmit_filtroMarca(event);">
    <div class="input-list p-0">
        <div class="form-check p-0">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="HP" id="marca_1" name="marca">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="marca_1">HP</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="Lenovo" id="marca_2" name="marca">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="marca_2">Lenovo</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="Intel Core i3" id="procesador_1" name="procesador">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="procesador_1">Intel Core i3</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="Intel Core i5" id="procesador_2" name="procesador">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="procesador_2">Intel Core i5</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" value="8 GB" id="ram_1" name="ram">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="ram_1">8 GB</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 text-center">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="btn_filtrar">Filtrar</button>
    </div>
</form>
```